# MIPS assembly programming: Storing integers in data section

Tags: assembly, mips

I know that to declare a variable inside the .data section we use-

```
.data
x: .word 2
```

But, what if I want to create a variable called answer which I will store the multiplication of x and some other variable into using SW.
Can I initialize a variable without putting any value into it? For ex-

```
answer: .word
```

Comment: Some assemblers support a special form such as `?` to declare uninitialized data, others have a different directive such as `.space` or `.skip`. Also, uninitialized and zero initialized variables are typically placed in special sections such as `.bss`. Some assemblers even have directives to allocate in `.bss` such as `.lcomm`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using SPIM, then use `.space n` to reserve n bytes. Source the "Data Declarations" section [here](http://logos.cs.uic.edu/366/notes/mips%20quick%20tutorial.htm).

You'll probably want `.space 8` given if you're using a 32 bit simulator, because multiplication can result in a number twice as large as the arguments (which are 4 bytes in 32 bit).